# How to manage/store encryption key in .Net smart card?

Tags: .net, security, encryption, smartcard, secret-key

I've been doing search here and read a lot of Q about the key but unfortunately no one was asking about smart card or any portable device.

Here is my question:

I have **smart card** storing sensitive medical info. , I need to **encrypt** this info using any symmetric algorithm inside the card.
But I am really confused about the **secret key**.

- where should I **store** it?
- is it must be generated every time I store new info?
- Should I choose one strong key and store it somewhere without changing ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear in the respect, what you are trying to protect using encryption and against what (hobby programmer, cryptologic expert, secret service). It is unlikely, that you want to prevent unauthorized extraction of the card, since smart cards and their operating system protect themselves sufficiently. It is also unlikely, that the legitimate host application does its processing in encrypted form. So most likely the reading process itself needs to be protected, which is obvious for contactless/NFC, but also a good idea for contact-based communication.

The important term here is **secure messaging**. Either you have a strong static key, which seldom needs to be changed, depending on the intensity of use, or, more common, you negotiate a session key, which may also depend on a (possibly fixed) secret. Both may be combined with a sequence counter, so even reading the same data in the session will provide different cryptograms. No matter, which way you choose, the key must be stored/computed on both sides. Part of the secret will need secure storage for itself, which depending on attacking potential might be in an encrypted file (with a completely different key) on disk, or in the extreme case, on a special smart card like device called a **security module**, which may have hardware resistance against tampering. (If not preventing the attack at least showing manipulation, e.g. by a broken security seal).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, actually i want to prevent unauthorized application from reading the data, using encryption so only authorized host application can decrypt the data and read them

Comment: @hum. Normally one would enforce this via an access rule, stating that reading of the file(s) containing the health data is only permitted after a challenge-response test, so encryption would not necessarily be needed. This still requires cryptography for the response computation, and the key for that must be present on both sides: host side for computation, card side for verification.